# Connect db2 via odbc C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, database, db2

Could some one please help me with this problem.

> ERROR [IM004] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLAllocHandle
>   on SQL_HANDLE_ENV failed Description: An unhandled exception occurred
>   during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about the error and where it
>   originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [IM004]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLAllocHandle on
>   SQL_HANDLE_ENV failed

I have tried many different things and nothing seems to work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

things i used:

Database Type: `ibmdb2`

my connection string :

```
Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DataBase=DOTNET;Hostname=XXXXXXX;
Port=50000;Protocol=TCPIP;Uid=ZZZZZZZZZ;Pwd=ZZZZZZZZZ;
```

I have installed ibm db2 driver for odbc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's the link on how to troubleshoot this [ERROR [IM004]](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21229860)